# Mongoose dynamic schema field

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I need to develop a model using mogoose with a field that will hold my object attributes. My problem is that these attributes are totaly changable, something like:

```
StockItem1 : {
    sku: 23492349,
    class: 'computer',
    subclass: 'printer',
    name: 'Hp Laserjet XXX',
    qty: 120,
    attr: {
        laser: true,
        speed: 1200,
        color: white
    }
}

StockItem2 : {
    sku: 22342349,
    class: 'homeappliance',
    subclass: 'refrigerator',
    name: 'GE Refrigerator',
    qty: 23,
    attr: {
        stainlessstell: true,
        doors: 2,
        frostfree: true
    }
}
```

The `attr` attributes fields are totally different depending of what type of `class/subclass` it belongs to.

What type should be given to `attr` field in mongoose ? I need to filter those in the future, like get all itens where `attr.doors == 2`.

Thanks for helping.

Comment: [`Mixed`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/2.7.x/docs/schematypes.html) ?

Comment: If they are actually "dependent" then you should be using ["discriminators"](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/discriminators.html), which would also help with your "class"  assignments.

Answer (score 3):

Use a Mixed Schema Type.  Here are the [docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html).  Mixed SchemaTypes are sort of an 'anything goes' type of deal.  You have flexibility when it comes to defining data but it makes your collection harder to maintain.